# Android Manifest intent issues

Tags: java, android, android-intent, manifest

In this app I want a button press to open a different Java file now I have done this many times before but I can't seem to get it to work now. i was just wondering if anyone can see what i have done wrong

this is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ucas.course"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SQLView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SQLVIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OTHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and this is how I start the intent

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        Intent temp = new Intent("android.intent.action.SQLVIEW");
        startActivity(temp);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no android.intent.category.OTHER, you probably meant android.intent.category.DEFAULT.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I can't believe I did that